# How can I use multiple Stored procedures on 1 Sub

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I write a code to retrieve to show data from Stored Procedure with ASP.NET like this

```
Private Sub AutoNumberVerification()
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(strConn.ToString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Try
        cmd.Connection = Conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Conn.Open()

        If (txtProducerID.Text.Trim.Length = 9) Then
            cmd.CommandText = "spProductCount"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtProducerID.Text)
        End If
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dt.Load(dr)

        If (convertInteger(dt.Rows(0)("estbProducerID").ToString) > 0) Then
            cmd.CommandText = "spProductCount"
            rdoEstbProducerList.Items.FindByValue(convertInteger(dt.Rows(0)("estbProducerID"))).Selected = True

        End If

        cmd.CommandText = "spProductCount"
        TextBox11.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ALL").ToString
        TextBox4.Text = dt.Rows(0)("FOOD").ToString
        TextBox5.Text = dt.Rows(0)("DRINKS").ToString
        TextBox6.Text = dt.Rows(0)("TAILOR").ToString
        TextBox7.Text = dt.Rows(0)("USABLE").ToString
        TextBox8.Text = dt.Rows(0)("HERB").ToString


        cmd.CommandText = "spProductproveCounts"
        TextBox12.Text = dt.Rows(0)("REGISTERED").ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("ERROR Load: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

but it show an error = "REGISTERED" is not belong to the table

how can I use two stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setting the cmd.CommandText to a stored procedure name will not execute it.  You still need to call ExecuteReader after each change to the CommandText